# Which Python API to connect to Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

It has been a long time since I connected to Oracle with Python. I *would* like a python-only solution, but this is not feasible, I guess, right? I will use that on a Linux machine (64bit Ubuntu or Debian).

A long time ago I used `cxOracle`, then I heard from `mxOracle`. What library is more current, better maintained, safer, etc. Or should I use something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using cx_Oracle perfectly well recently.

The API doesn't need to change as frequently as the db and [cx_Oracle 5.1.1](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/) was released at the end of last year.

Comment: +1 for cx_Oracle, I've been using that for many years without any issues.